# how to check if the link is clickable in a column

Tags: java, selenium

I have multiple links in a column, only one is enabled randomly and others are disabled, I need check which link is enabled and then click it.

I am using regular expressions to find the link, but how can i put in loop and  check  Kindly help

Below is the code

```
int i = 0;
do {                         
  xpath =".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_dgDataList_ctl0"+i+"_btnEdit']";
  a1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isEnabled();
  System.out.println(a1+"" + i);
  i = i+1;
} while (a1 = true);


driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).Click();
```

Comment: Can you share some HTML code please?? and where is the regular expression?

Comment: If you see the xpath  ,  i added  "i"  where the value is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information to give a definitive answer. So the following is my best guess.

You can cheat using [ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) method, something like:

```
// assume driver is already initialized to some WebDriver
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement clickableBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, '_btnEdit']")));
clickableBtn.click();
```

Comment: I have multiple links in a column, only one is enabled randomly and others are disabled, I need check which link is enabled and then click it.

I am using regular expressions to find the link, but how can i put in loop and click Kindly help

Below is the code

Comment: int i = 0;
do {                         
  xpath =".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_dgDataList_ctl0"+i+"_btnEdit']";
  a1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isEnabled();
  System.out.println(a1+"" + i);
  i = i+1;
} while (a1 = true);


driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).Click();

Comment: @RakeshKumar If you have a new question, please start a new question. If you are adding information to this current question, please edit the current question. Providing code in comments makes it completely illegible.